# Coding IF statements in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have created a Risk Log in Excel, there are two columns, labels Priority & Impact (where High (H), Medium (M) or Low (L) can be inputted). I would like to create a third column called "Measure". 
This will calculate a value based on the priority and the impact of these risks.
The numbers are shown in the table below, where the horizontal axis is Impact, and the Vertical in Priority

```
 H  3   7   9
 M  2   5   8
 L  1   4   6
    L   M   H
Impact
```

So for example, a priority of H and an impact of H would give you 9 in the measure column, a priority of M and an impact of H would give you 8, and a priority of H and an impact of M would give you 7.
I am not quite sure how to code the "Measure" column so that I get the number desired. I am  assuming some kind of "If" statement, but not sure as there are so many options. Below is my current spreadsheet, and I would like to add the measure column to the right.

Any help is great!

[image: Impact X Probability]

Comment: Is it intentional that the top row goes 3 7 9 and not 3 6 9?

Comment: @TomSharpe They probably want to avoid duplicating the 6. These grids are never perfect.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with an Index/Match lookup. No nesting of IFs required.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$3,MATCH(F2,$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH(G2,$B$4:$D$4,0))
```

Copy down. You can place the lookup table on a different sheet, of course.

[image]

The first Match function finds the row according to the values in A1 to A3. The second Match finds the column according to the values in B4 to D4. Index returns the cell where the found row and column cross.

Comment: thank you!! one more question, I have dragged the code down so that all future risks will be able to calculate "measure". Now all the empty ones say #N/A since the Probability and Impact columns are empty, is it possibly to make it so that these cells looks blank until the rest are filled in ? Thanks!

Comment: =if(f2="","",INDEX($B$1:$D$3,MATCH(F2,$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH(G2,$B$4:$D$4,0)))

Comment: Pre-filling formulas into empty rows will not be needed if you turn your table into an Excel Table object with Insert > table. In an Excel Table, formulas, formatting, data validation, etc, get applied to new rows automatically.

Comment: @teylyn Thank you very much! THis is the current code I have =IFERROR(INDEX('Risk Metrics'!$D$6:$F$8,MATCH(Open!L6,'Risk Metrics'!$C$6:$C$8,0),MATCH(Open!M6,'Risk Metrics'!$D$9:$F$9,0)),"") However, this is in a pivot table, and when I sort via the other columns in the table, the values get messed up and do not match the Impact/Probability values for that risk. Is there a way I can adjust this code so that when sorted, the values stay the same? Thanks