# Filtering numerically calculated columns in Excel

Tags: excel, filter

I have created a risk catalog in Excel, all the values are manually input, except a column called measure.

Here is my question regarding the code in the measure column, not sure if it is necessary to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963950/coding-if-statements-in-excel) or not that calculates a risk value values on inputted impact/probability values.

When I go to add a filter arrow to this column, and then try and filter from high to low, it messed up my columns and the values do not match what they are supposed to. Is there at reason that this does not filter properly?

Is it due to the fact that it is a calculated column? Additionally, sometimes when I add the filter column, It will only let me filter A-Z when the values in the columns are numerical.

Comment: Sounds like you have text that looks like numbers instead of actual numbers.

Comment: do you know how I can fix this?, my code only outputs numerical values (1-9)

Comment: Put `1` in an empty cell.  Copy the cell containing the `1`.  Select your range that needs to actually be numbers -> Right-click -> Paste-special -> Multiply -> OK

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, we'd need to see representative sample data (doesn't have to be the real data), along with the formula you're using.

Comment: Just to be clear, your problem is when **sorting**, maybe **sorting filtered data**, not specifically with filters.